# What is undefined function when I use Ghidra to dissemble a .so file?

Tags: linux, reverse-engineering, dynamic-linking, ghidra

I am now trying to dissemble a `.so` file and I found a strange part :

[image]

And follow `FUN_004d9f38` lead me to this :

[image]

Can any one help me understanding what is so called `undefined __cdecl FUN_004d9f38(void)`,  specifically what is a `undefinde` function.

As the code show above. the first picture's code use a jump instruction jump into `FUN_004d9f38`, but the `FUN_004d9f38` is a invalid instruction code of `67`. How can the program manage to still work properly ?

Comment: what happens if you press `d` having the cursor at `67h`?

Comment: I tried, nothing really happend, I assume that this is some tricks with code obfuscation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` is a special data type, that Ghidra uses to to mark locations where the type is not known/defined yet. If you right click the function name and `Edit Function` you should see a window like this that makes this clearer:

[image]

if you change the datatype in the list to e.g. `qword` you get `qword FUN_1000081e0` instead of `undefined FUN_1000081e0`:

[image]